# Using "ceil' To Make A function With seamless Changes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, wave-equation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**I'm trying to use ceil and or floor to accomplish something arrived at in another post. See lower two images for details: The uppermost image (of the two) is my question and the next is the answer.**

After a prior post, I thought of the idea of using ceil to make a sine wave function where some of the values change seamlessly (and instantly). Say, from 1, 2, 3, etc... . What I got (**see uppermost fig.**) was a partial sine wave; a sine wave that was broken into pieces. Does anyone know what's happening or more importantly how to use ceil to make a function with seamless changes and without gaps?

Thank you for your time and talent.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don not understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @copper.hat
I want to use ceil, or floor for that matter, to decrease the angle, "360," over time in steps. That is, every "360," "1" will be added to the power 0.5 is raised to. In other words it will jump values without intermediary steps.

Comment: @copper.hat Maybe I just don't understand ceil and floor; but I've used other functions for this.

Comment: $\lceil {t \over 360} \rceil$. Ceiling of $x$ is the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to $x$. $\lceil 0.5 \rceil = 1$, $\lceil 1 \rceil = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat, thank you; but what will square brackets do?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that's what I thought. That's exactly what I wanted, so why is the graph 'missing parts ' instead of just changing values?

Comment: @copper.hat, I edited my post to better explain things. See post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time & energy to work through what you have above, but it seems like it would be straightforward to debug.

Comment: @copper.hat, that's ok. Thank you for the time.